# MKMapView is veeeeery slow in simulator, Xcode 9

Tags: ios, xcode, mkmapview

I have some strange situation, maybe you can help me with it. MBP 13"/i5/8ram, High Sierra, XCODE 9. 
Im working with some youtube lessons of Obj-C, and now Im on MKMapView, when I put this in storyboard on ViewController, and start simulator (iPhone X, 8 Plus, or any iPads) it`s load with terrible speed, 1 double click for zoom ~ 15sec. waiting, but when simulator definitely fully render the map (I check this from mapViewDidFinishRenderingMap) any other zooming need to wait the same time with freezing map, what it can be? never seen same effect before, mac hardware, I think, not so bad, any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Which version of Xcode 9.  The first releases definitely had an issue with map views

Comment: How are you on disk space?  If it is low, then you may find the system swapping too much (thrashing).

Comment: 160+GB SSD free, also I clean system with CleanMyMac and reboot it. Xcode Version 9.0 (9A235), Im just checking in auto-update tab in AppStore - nothing, but when I enter in the search XCode, what I see??? VERSION 9.2! CMON! where my auto-update!! Anyway thanks you guys! I think this is help me :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift 4.0 MapView Running Slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46967513/swift-4-0-mapview-running-slow)