# Is iOS simulator MKMapView performance improved in OS Catalina?

Tags: opengl, ios-simulator, mkmapview, metal, macos-catalina

A long standing issue with the iOS simulator is its laggy/jerky performance on iOS simulator, even in Apples Maps app. I am doing a lot of development on an MKMapView and am thinking to upgrade to Mac OS Catalina in the hopes that the rendering in the simulator will be fixed.

Does the simulator completely run in its own box hence not affected by OS upgrade? If not, has anyone seen any worthwhile improvements (if any) of going to Catalina?

Note: I have tried changing [rendering modules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46967567/870565) and only saw tiny improvements, nothing significant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, when using the iOS 13+ runtimes, which support Metal on Catalina.

Check out [Getting the Most Out of Simulator - WWDC 2019](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/418/) for more information and some nice comparisons in the video (check out around 32 minutes into the video).

Comment: Following your answer, I installed Catalina, and indeed, the iOS 13 +simulator is lightyears ahead on speed.